# How I can get the mean of binary combination?

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

[image]

My data is shown above. I have 9 binary variables and there can be 27 combinations from 9 binary variables. I want to get sum or mean value of raltv in terms of 27 combinations.
In other words, I want to get 3 of 3X3 tables and the elements of the table are mean (raltv) (or sum (raltv)) of each combination. 
Moreover, I also want to frequency value in each combination.

Comment: Oh sorry. from risk(high,low,mid),xtran(high,low,mid) and interest(high,low,mid). We have 27 combination. Please help me.

Comment: @Frank, actually I think it would be 2^9 or 512 possible combinations. What I think the OP has though is 3^3 = 27 possibilities as you can only choose low/mid/high for each of the 3 clusters of variables.

Comment: Yea, I got that wrong.  Shame on me.

Comment: @user3714137 In the future, please provide sample data that others can easily use (see how thelatemail had to provide sample data?) and your desired result. This saves everyone time and effort, reduces guesswork, and increases the chances that you get what you want. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Frank!. I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the columns are mutually exclusive, I think you'd ultimately be better off collapsing each of those groups of 3 columns to one variable labelled 1/2/3 or low/mid/hi and then using tapply to calculate means in each group. E.g.:

```
dat <- data.frame(raltv=1:6,one_low=c(1,1,0,0,0,0),one_med=c(0,0,1,1,0,0),one_hi =c(0,0,0,0,1,1),two_low=c(1,1,0,0,0,0),two_med=c(0,0,1,1,0,0),two_hi =c(0,0,0,0,1,1),thr_low=c(1,1,0,0,0,0),thr_med=c(0,0,1,1,0,0),thr_hi =c(0,0,0,0,1,1))
```

Looking like:

```
  raltv one_low one_med one_hi two_low two_med two_hi thr_low thr_med thr_hi
1     1       1       0      0       1       0      0       1       0      0
2     2       1       0      0       1       0      0       1       0      0
3     3       0       1      0       0       1      0       0       1      0
4     4       0       1      0       0       1      0       0       1      0
5     5       0       0      1       0       0      1       0       0      1
6     6       0       0      1       0       0      1       0       0      1
```

Process it:

```
dat$one <- c("low","med","hi")[col(dat[2:4])[dat[2:4]==1]]
dat$two <- c("low","med","hi")[col(dat[5:7])[dat[5:7]==1]]
dat$thr <- c("low","med","hi")[col(dat[8:10])[dat[8:10]==1]]

tapply(dat$raltv,dat[c("one","two","thr")],mean)

#, , thr = hi
# 
#     two
#one    hi low med
#  hi  5.5  NA  NA
#  low  NA  NA  NA
#  med  NA  NA  NA
#  
#, , thr = low
# 
#     two
#one   hi low med
#  hi  NA  NA  NA
#  low NA 1.5  NA
#  med NA  NA  NA
# 
#, , thr = med
# 
#     two
#one   hi low med
#  hi  NA  NA  NA
#  low NA  NA  NA
#  med NA  NA 3.5
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. Can you let me know how I can collapse each of those groups of 3 columns to one variable ? Your suggestion does not work when 1 values are not orderly arranged like your example.